# Reading a text file into node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just getting started with node.js. This is my first attempt ever and I'm having trouble reading from a txt file to the node.js terminal in windows 7. Using the Node.js application in windows, I typed "node sample.js" and the sample.js and sample.txt files are in a folder on my desktop but the node.exe application doesnt read the file. Also I'm not sure how it would know the directory path Any insight? Here's my code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Starting");
fs.readFile("sample.txt", function(error, data) {
    console.log("Contents of file: " + data);
});
console.log("Carrying on executing");
```

Comment: Did you check the error?  Add a line `if(error) throw error;` before you print out the data

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the `error` parameter (log it or throw it) to see what's going wrong.  Because you're using a relative path, it will be looking relative to the current working directory.

[node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

> Relative path to filename can be used, remember however that this path will be relative to process.cwd().

You should also be aware that the last line of your code will actually execute first (probably) because `readFile` is asynchronous. (This is a key node.js concept.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/sample.txt", function(error, data) {
```

__dirname is actually the current directory of the file which you are in.